# Tuning query - reduce temporary and/or filesort use with join

Tags: mysql, performance, join, mysql-5.7, performance-tuning

My query runs in 60-90 seconds, I would like to see how can I improve it.
One table contain partitions and have tens of million rows each partition.
The other table contain 5-8 million rows between two `siteId`.
Basically the join gives the actual `ID` by `mLongId`. I'm wondering if I can remove the `Using temporary; Using filesort` or use more columns in the `used_key_parts` step.

`dt` is `datetime` but we save there only date, meaning `where r.dt = '2021-01-01'` returns everything for that day.

@Rick James, Good catch about the function. I will convert `tMovies` into `utf8mb4`.

**Update:** after table rebuild and new unique index (see below) - plan looks different and SQL runs at 10-39s (used to be 60-80s) - I'm putting the new plan at the end of this Q. Would be nice to hear farther tuning.

```
tMovies: UNIQUE index ux_covering (mLongId,siteId,movieId,catalogId,uId)
```

Select:

```
select t.siteId, 
    r.dt,  
    t.movieId as movieId, 
    t.catalogId as catalogId,
    t.uId as uId, 
    r.sysId,
    sum(r.views) as views
from raw r
inner join tMovies t on r.mLongId = t.mLongId and t.movieId is not null and r.siteId = t.siteId
where r.dt = '2021-01-01' and r.siteId=2
group by t.siteId, t.movieId, t.catalogId, t.uId, r.dt, r.sysId

raw :  KEY `ix_composite` (`dt`,`siteId`,`mLongId`,`sysId`,`views`)
tMovies : KEY `ix_composite` (`siteId`,`movieId`,`mLongId`,`catalogId`,`uId`)


+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-----------------+---------+------------------+----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | key             | key_len | ref              | rows     | filtered | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-----------------+---------+------------------+----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | NULL       | range | ix_composite    | 10      | NULL             | 10098009 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | p20210101  | ref   | ix_composite    | 1028    | const,const,func |        1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-----------------+---------+------------------+----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

and

```
EXPLAIN: {
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "9501888.33"
    },
    "grouping_operation": {
      "using_temporary_table": true,
      "using_filesort": true,
      "nested_loop": [
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "t",
            "access_type": "range",
            "possible_keys": [
              "movieId",
              "ix_composite"
            ],
            "key": "ix_composite",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "siteId",
              "movieId"
            ],
            "key_length": "10",
            "rows_examined_per_scan": 10098009,
            "rows_produced_per_join": 5049004,
            "filtered": "100.00",
            "using_index": true,
            "cost_info": {
              "read_cost": "336601.27",
              "eval_cost": "1009800.90",
              "prefix_cost": "2356203.07",
              "data_read_per_join": "1G"
            },
            "used_columns": [
              "id",
              "mLongId",
              "siteId",
              "movieId",
              "catalogId",
              "uId"
            ],
            "attached_condition": "((`st`.`t`.`siteId` = 3) and (`st`.`t`.`movieId` is not null))"
          }
        },
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "r",
            "partitions": [
              "p20210101"
            ],
            "access_type": "ref",
            "possible_keys": [
              "ix_composite"
            ],
            "key": "ix_song_day_composite",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "dt",
              "siteId",
              "mLongId"
            ],
            "key_length": "1028",
            "ref": [
              "const",
              "const",
              "func"
            ],
            "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
            "rows_produced_per_join": 8393250,
            "filtered": "100.00",
            "using_index": true,
            "cost_info": {
              "read_cost": "5467035.22",
              "eval_cost": "1678650.05",
              "prefix_cost": "9501888.33",
              "data_read_per_join": "8G"
            },
            "used_columns": [
              "id",
              "siteId",
              "mLongId",
              "sysId",
              "views",
              "dt"
            ],
            "attached_condition": "(`st`.`r`.`mLongId` = convert(`st`.`t`.`mLongId` using utf8mb4))"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE raw (
  id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  siteId tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  mLongId varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'spotify song id (href) / apple id',
  sysId int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  views bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  dt datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id,dt),
  KEY ix_composite (dt,siteId,mLongId,sysId,views)
) CHARSET=utf8mb4
PARTITION BY RANGE  COLUMNS(dt)
(PARTITION p20171201 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-01-01'),
 PARTITION p20180101 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-02-01'),
 PARTITION p20180201 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-03-01'),
 PARTITION p20180301 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-04-01'),
 PARTITION p20180401 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-05-01'),
 PARTITION p20180501 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-06-01'),
 PARTITION p20180601 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-07-01'),
 PARTITION p20180701 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-08-01'),
 PARTITION p20180801 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-09-01'),
 PARTITION p20180901 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-10-01'),
 PARTITION p20181001 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-11-01'),
 PARTITION p20181101 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-12-01'),
 PARTITION p20181201 VALUES LESS THAN ('2019-01-01'),
 PARTITION p20190101 VALUES LESS THAN ('2019-02-01'),
 PARTITION p20190201 VALUES LESS THAN ('2019-03-01'),
 PARTITION p20190301 VALUES LESS THAN ('2019-04-01'),
 PARTITION p20190401 VALUES LESS THAN ('2019-05-01'),
 PARTITION p20190501 VALUES LESS THAN ('2019-06-01'),
 PARTITION p20190601 VALUES LESS THAN ('2019-07-01'),
 PARTITION p20190701 VALUES LESS THAN ('2019-08-01'),
 PARTITION p20190801 VALUES LESS THAN ('2019-09-01'),
 PARTITION p20190901 VALUES LESS THAN ('2019-10-01'),
 PARTITION p20191001 VALUES LESS THAN ('2019-11-01'),
 PARTITION p20191101 VALUES LESS THAN ('2019-12-01'),
 PARTITION p20191201 VALUES LESS THAN ('2020-01-01'),
 PARTITION p20200101 VALUES LESS THAN ('2020-02-01'),
 PARTITION p20200201 VALUES LESS THAN ('2020-03-01'),
 PARTITION p20200301 VALUES LESS THAN ('2020-04-01'),
 PARTITION p20200401 VALUES LESS THAN ('2020-05-01'),
 PARTITION p20200501 VALUES LESS THAN ('2020-06-01'),
 PARTITION p20200601 VALUES LESS THAN ('2020-07-01'),
 PARTITION p20200701 VALUES LESS THAN ('2020-08-01'),
 PARTITION p20200801 VALUES LESS THAN ('2020-09-01'),
 PARTITION p20200901 VALUES LESS THAN ('2020-10-01'),
 PARTITION p20201001 VALUES LESS THAN ('2020-11-01'),
 PARTITION p20201101 VALUES LESS THAN ('2020-12-01'),
 PARTITION p20201201 VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-01-01'),
 PARTITION p20210101 VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-02-01'),
 PARTITION p20210201 VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-03-01'),
 PARTITION p20210301 VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-04-01'))
 
 
CREATE TABLE tMovies (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  mLongId varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  siteId int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  movieId int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  catalogId int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  uId int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY mLongId (mLongId),
  UNIQUE index ux_covering (mLongId,siteId,movieId,catalogId,uId),
  KEY ix_composite (siteId,movieId,mLongId,catalogId,uId),
) CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

**Updated plan after table rebuild with utf8mb4:**

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+--------------+---------+-------------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | key          | key_len | ref               | rows    | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+--------------+---------+-------------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | p20210101  | ref  | ix_composite | 6       | const,const       | 1285520 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | NULL       | ref  | ux_covering  | 1028    | st.r.mLongId,const|       1 |    50.00 | Using where; Using index                     |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+--------------+---------+-------------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------+

EXPLAIN: {
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "1965128.98"
    },
    "grouping_operation": {
      "using_temporary_table": true,
      "using_filesort": true,
      "nested_loop": [
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "r",
            "partitions": [
              "p20210101"
            ],
            "access_type": "ref",
            "possible_keys": [
              "ix_composite"
            ],
            "key": "ix_composite",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "dt",
              "siteId"
            ],
            "key_length": "6",
            "ref": [
              "const",
              "const"
            ],
            "rows_examined_per_scan": 1285520,
            "rows_produced_per_join": 1285520,
            "filtered": "100.00",
            "using_index": true,
            "cost_info": {
              "read_cost": "160690.88",
              "eval_cost": "257104.00",
              "prefix_cost": "417794.88",
              "data_read_per_join": "1G"
            },
            "used_columns": [
              "id",
              "siteId",
              "mLongId",
              "sysId",
              "views",
              "dt"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "t",
            "access_type": "ref",
            "possible_keys": [
              "mLongId",
              "ux_covering",
              "ix_composite"
            ],
            "key": "ux_covering",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "mLongId",
              "siteId"
            ],
            "key_length": "1028",
            "ref": [
              "st.r.mLongId",
              "const"
            ],
            "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
            "rows_produced_per_join": 650006,
            "filtered": "50.00",
            "using_index": true,
            "cost_info": {
              "read_cost": "1287331.58",
              "eval_cost": "130001.26",
              "prefix_cost": "1965128.98",
              "data_read_per_join": "654M"
            },
            "used_columns": [
              "id",
              "mLongId",
              "siteId",
              "movieId",
              "catalogId",
              "uId"
            ],
            "attached_condition": "(`st`.`t`.`movieId` is not null)"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r: INDEX(siteId, dt)
t: INDEX(siteId, mLongId, movieId)
```

What datatype is `dt`?  If it is `DATETIME`, then `r.dt = '2021-01-01'` only checks for midnight.  If you really wanted all day, then do

```
WHERE ...
  AND r.dt >= '2021-01-01'
  AND r.dt  < '2021-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

If it is datatype `DATE` then your formulation is OK.  (And my formulation and index are not broken.)

(My suggested index is already set up for this change.)

What is the table `PARTITIONed` on?  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table; there may be other issues to investigate.)  I see "func" in the Explain; that sounds 'bad'; the `SHOWs` should clarify what is going on.

"Filesort" and "temporary" are symptoms of a problem; they are not necessarily the villains.  My suggestions are designed to speed up the query; I don't now whether they will eliminate them.

The *order* of the columns in an index is important in helping the columns be used.  As soon as a "range" is hit, no further "used_key_parts" will be used.  `IS NOT NULL` is a range test.

**More**

Datatypes should be the same in both tables when `JOINing`.  `mLongId` can't use an index untile you get the `COLLATION to be the same.  (Numeric consistency is less critical -- cf` siteId.)

In general, it not efficient to start any index with the column being `PARTITIONed` on.  (I am thinking of `dt`.)  Partition pruning is already doing some filtering on the column, so you may as well start the index with something else.

If `t.id` is not used anywhere else, get rid of it and `PRIMARY KEY`, then update the `UNIQUE.mLongId` to be the PK.

So far, I don't see any benefit in the partitioning (versus what could be done with just indexes).  Perhaps some other queries benefit from partitioning?

Looking at just this:

```
ON   r.mLongId = t.mLongId
and  r.siteId = t.siteId
```

Since `t.mLongId` is `UNIQUE`, if the Optimizer decides to start with `r`, then when it moves on to `t`, `mLongId` will specify only one row.  The test on `siteId` seems unnecessary.  (Actually, all it can do is filter out the row if `siteId` does not match.)  My point is:  There may be a bug in the query.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I've updated my question.

Comment: @Nir - I added some more.

Comment: so the partitioning is not done for SQL performance. it is done for drop partition, better insert performance( on multi TB table - indexes reduce load time drastically w/o partitioning). I know make `dt` first in the index is not idea but `storeId` and `dt` are the only columns in the `where` clause... also, I include the `storeId` so the proper index will be picked as well as the part of covering index

Comment: BTW I have attached new plan and new IX

Comment: @Nir - Yes, `PARTITIONing`, _in this case_, is very beneficial.  I discuss it further in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint .

Comment: @Nir - Did you _replace_ the `UNIQUE`?  If so, you have _lost_ the uniqueness constraint on `(mLongId)`.  And have added a less-restrictive (and probably useless) uniqueness constraint on the combo of 5 columns.  Please update the `CREATE TABLE` to clarify.  (After that, I may look for more improvements.)

Comment: I have not replaced it because of the reason you mentioned :) I added another for `mLongId,siteId` and for the covering columns.